# Compress input generated by a for loop

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, gzip

I'm trying to generate a big list of words in a for loop. I'd prefer to compress it in the same step without creating a temporary text-file.
My code is like that (which doesn't seem to work... the compressed file is too big):

```
for ((a = 0; a <= 1000; a++));
do
   echo "some_generated_word" | gzip >> output.txt.zip
done
```

What's wrong with this command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
for ((a = 0; a <= 1000; a++)); do
   echo "some_generated_word"
done | gzip > output.gz
```

There is no need to use redirect inside the loop, just use it after the `done` as showed above.

Comment: Don't you *need* to move the pipe out of the loop to avoid geting multiple gzip headers in the final output?

Comment: Ah I think I got it now, Thanks so muc  @TomFenech, edited now.